# storing values from database for later use in php

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I' trying to bring data from a table in a MSSQL database and I want to store the data from 2 columns in that table to use them later . this is the code I wrote :

```
<?php

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$sql=" SELECT * FROM produit";
$version = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($version)){
    $num=$row['num_prod'];
    $des=$row['designation_prod'];}
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

I want those the values inside those columns in a table, I don't seem to find any recourses on this as I am new to PHP, it would be of great help if someone pointed me in the right direction

Comment: what is the purpose of the `echo("<table>");` you are also echoing the closing table tag and closing the database with the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `$num` & `$des` to an array:

```php
$results = [];
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($version)){
    $results[] = [
        $row['num_prod'],
        $row['designation_prod']
    ];
}

// $results can then be used later.
```